# X11 hangs while plotting in R

Tags: macos, r, x11

While plotting to a window in R, X11 kept hanging. These steps reproduce the error.

```
plot(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
```

X11 window becomes active. Press [Apple]+[Tab] to go back to the terminal window.

```
dev.new()
```

Second X11 window becomes active. Press [Apple]+[Tab] to go back to the terminal window.

Making sure you are in the terminal and you are not holding down any keys, press [Apple]+[Tab] again to try to go to X11. The X11 is no longer responding!

Setup details: I am on OSX 10.7.3 with R and xorg-* installed through Macports. R.app in /Applications does not seem to have this problem. I can give  more details if they will be helpful.

This is from Activity Monitor/inspect:

[image]

The sampling of the process is at http://pastebin.com/3rXM2BBn

Comment: Recommend you submit this to the R-sig-mac mailing list.  But make sure you provide your version of R, your version of X11, and your hardware (CPU, Mac model).  Also: does this happen if you use R.app instead of the command line?  Do you actually get the "not responding" flag in the process monitor?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thanks! I might submit it to R-sig-mac, I just find it easier to update info and images here. Yes, activity monitor shows not responding.

Comment: Cross-posted on r-sig-mac : https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/attachments/20120406/0028af5a/attachment.pl

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is a bug in Apple's X11, which has been fixed in xorg-server. From the cross-post: 
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33914